# How to get cart data inside array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have 2 products in my cart session. and want me to combine in array **data_order**. but read only 1 product. actually this data I will send in an email so from that I make the format of the data like this.

my controller :

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item){

    if($item['diskon'] == "0"){
        $harga_before = $item['before'];
        $harga_after = $item['price'];
    }else{
        $harga_before = $item['before'];
        $harga_after = $item['price'];
    }

    foreach ($this->cart->product_options($item['rowid']) as $option_name => $option_value){
        if(empty($option_value)){
            $option_size = "";
            $option_color = "";
        }else{
            $option = $item['options'];
            $option_size = $option['Size'];
            $option_color =  $option['Warna'];
        }
    }

        $data = array(
            'inv'        => $invoice,
            'tglOrdercs' => date('d F Y H:i:s'),
            'tglExp'     => $date_maju,
            'nmlkp'      => $nmlkpi,
            'almtkp'     => $address,
            'noTelp'     => $notelp271,
            'methode'    => $method,
            'bnk_option' => $banking_select,
            'data_order' => array(
                            'nama_produk'   => $item['name'],
                            'artikel'       => $item['artikel'],
                            'diskon'        => $item['diskon'],
                            'ukuran'        => $option_size,
                            'warna'         => $option_color,
                            'qty'           => $item['qty'],
                            'harga_fix'     => $harga_after,
                            'harga_before'  => $harga_before,               
                        ),
        );
    }
```

my result :

```
Array(
[inv] =&gt; STJOHB9261JR
[tglOrdercs] =&gt; 28 September 2017 11:23:33
[tglExp] =&gt; 28 September 2017 21:23:33
[nmlkp] =&gt; danny setyawan
[almtkp] =&gt; Perum puspa sari H22 sidoarjo
[noTelp] =&gt; 089263423647
[methode] =&gt; Transfer
[bnk_option] =&gt; Bank BNI
[data_order] =&gt; Array
    (
        [nama_produk] =&gt; Sonic TL Brown
        [artikel] =&gt; CH2002-831
        [diskon] =&gt; 40
        [ukuran] =&gt; 39
        [warna] =&gt; Coklat
        [qty] =&gt; 2
        [harga_fix] =&gt; 125340
        [harga_before] =&gt; 208900
    )
```

)

ignore ">", this result from browser console.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What you want to ask here ? Is there any error you are facing ?

Comment: I want to get my shopping cart data. the results I get can only be 1 data when in the shopping cart there are more than 1 product

Comment: print_r($this->cart->contents()); and check if you are getting multiple data or single ?

Comment: after i print_r  cart data is multiple. i want multiple cart data 
can be entered into the **data_order**